# PHP: How to match all occurences of a regex pattern in a document

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, data-munging

I am doing some data munging on documents which may (or may not - as the case may be) have ocurrence(s) of a regular expression pattern in their content.

I would like to write a PHP function to use to process the documents - the job of the function is to return an array of all matching patterns sound in the document (if they exist), or to return an empty array if no matches were found.

I am sure that this involves using the PHP function [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), however, I do not understand the format of the array returned by preg_match_all. I simply want to return a 1 dimensional (i.e. non-nested array) of the strings that match as follows:

```
<?php 

   $pattern = "^[h].[a-z]{3,4}";
   $doc = file_get_contents('some_pathname');

   function get_matching_patterns($pattern, $doc){
     $out = array();

     if (strlen($doc) && strlen($pattern)){
        // not sure about this - I don't like the complicated nested array returned
        // by preg_match-all
        preg_match_all($pattern, $doc, $out); 
     }

     return out;
   }
?>
```

Comment: $out ($ missing). try to print_r($out) or var_dump. you'll see the structure

Comment: and **doc** and **pattern** are missing a $ as well -> **$doc**, **$pattern**

Comment: Sorry, problem of switching back and forth between too many languages!. Sometimes, I forget PHP requires sigils!. I'll fix the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You're missing a $
- In your case you can simply return `$out[0]`

Comment: What happens in the case of more than one match being returned?. Is $out[0] a nested array? I mean if $out[0] is **ALWAYS GUARANTEED** to be a nested array (when patterns match), then I can simply process it and return a non nested array of the matches. Is this what you are suggesting (or did I misunderstand)?

Comment: `$out[0]` is the array containing all matched entries. There's no `$out[1]` for your pattern. If you had a regex like `#([h].)[a-z]{3,4}#` (note the parentheses) you would find the `[h].` parts in `$out[1]`.